# Conversion of datetime to date and time

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, date

I am getting datetime from mongoDB as (May 10, 2016 4:14:16 PM). I want to convert this into two part and use that in my angular application. First Date and second time.

Date should be like: 10 May 2016
Time should be like: 16:14

can you please help me here. Thanks a lot

Comment: Angular has methods to format the timestamp however you need it to appear https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [format](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) it:

```
 Date: {{date_expression | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
 Time: {{date_expression | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrbhno62/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was missing 'convert string to date' first part.